# How to retrieve the display resolution?

Tags: c++, qt4

How do I retrieve the current display resolution in Qt4 or Qt5? For example, if I have my display resolution set to 1366x768, then how do I obtain this value in my application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to get the dimension of the QT desktop widget

```
#include 

qDebug () << QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry();
```

It gives back a QRect, which offers functions to get the height and the width.

Comment: Thans for answer. I did this in my app:

QRect dims = app.desktop()->screenGeometry() ;
qDebug("%d, %d", dims.width(), dims.height()) ;

whwre app is QApplication instance, and it works